# How to calculate the average of class fields

Tags: java

Given that you have five input values and "average" method, calculate the average value for the five input values inside the average method and return it.
Note: average is the total summation of the values divided by its count

```
public class MyCalculator {

    int input1 = 10;
    int input2 = 20;
    int input3 = 30;
    int input4 = 40;
    int input5 = 50;

    public float average() {

             return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Use below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to get average on using average function

```
public class MyCalculator {
     int input1 = 10;      
     int input2 = 20; 
     int input3 = 30; 
     int input4 = 40; 
     int input5 = 50; 

     public float average() {
              return (input1 + input2+input3+input4+input5)/5;
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this function to calculate average :

```
public float avg(int ...a)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }

    return (sum/a.length) ;
}
```